# finding whether vector equation passes through a point

Tags: vectors

say that I have a vector equation, $(x,y,z)=(2,1,1)+t(1,0,1)$
and given a few points, $(1,1,0),(1,1,1),(3,1,3)$

How do I actually check for whether they passes through those points?

Comment: If there's some $t$ such that, for instance, $(1,1,0)=(2,1,1)+t(1,0,1)$.

Comment: so as long as t is solvable, it pass through the point?

Comment: @user317339 Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a line, which can be written in cartesian form as
$$\frac{x-2}{1}=\frac{y-1}{0}=\frac{z-1}{1}=t$$
Any general point on it is of the form $P(t+2,1,t+1)$

Now those points for which the value of $t$ is consistent lie on the line and others don't. (Example $(1,1,0)$ lies on the line for $t=-1$)

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

This vector equation represents a line in 3D.The part"t(1,0,1)"means the direction of the line,the other part means the line is through the point (2,1,1).So determining whether this equation is through some point,you just make this point subtract (2,1,1) ,then check if this difference (i.e some point-(2,1,1)) is the multiple of the vector (1,0,1).I think this is analogous to the situation in the 2D place